# $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1} dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1} dx$
Using the residue theorem, we can evaluate the integral of $f(z) = \frac{z^2+1}{z^4+1}$ over the upper half of a semicircular contour $C$ with radius $R$ and center at the origin, followed by the integral over the x-axis from $-R$ to $R$. The singular points of $f(z)$ are $z=e^{i\pi/4}$ and $z=e^{3i\pi/4}$.

By finding the residues of $f(z)$ at these singular points, we can apply the residue theorem to evaluate the integral over the semicircular contour. Taking the limit as $R\to\infty$ ...

that was my prof. solution ,
my question is why he took only 2 points which is ${i\pi/4}$ and ${3i\pi/4}$
what about the other point ${+2in\pi}$ ?

Comment: You could take the lower part of the semicircle of radius $R$ that contains the other two 4-roots of the unity as poles. You get a similar result.

Comment: no that's not my question , my question is why don't we take as well
${i(1+2n)\pi/4}$
not the points under x axis

Comment: The counter should have a *large* segment on the real axis to get $\mathbb{R}$ in the limit. Whether you choose the upper to lower part pf the circle is not that important for along the circular parts the contribution of the counter integral is small. That is why two of the quartic roots of the unit are left out in each choice.

Comment: Brother , I understand you , and that's not my question you are answering!

why we took only ${i\pi/4}$ and not ${5i\pi/4}$ and ${9i\pi/4}$ ...

Comment: From my understanding, I think that taking every pole doesn't matter here. You just need a contour with a path that covers the bounds of the original integral.

Comment: There are only four quartic roots!

Comment: $e^{\pi i / 4}$ and $e^{9 \pi i / 4}$ are the same number.

Comment: The poles $e^{i\pi/4}$ and $e^{3i\pi/4}$ are the only two poles in the contour, and they are equal to $e^{i\pi/4 + 2n\pi i}$ and $e^{3i\pi/4 + 2n\pi i}$, respectively (for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: You don't take the points under the x-axis because they don't contribute to your contour.